# How far in can tile be installed around bathtub window?

Tags: bathroom, windows, bathtub

I was wondering how far in can tile be placed around the window sill of a bathtub window?  The glass window and the tile may be close to flush or about 1/8 inch from the glass part of the window.

Is that normal?  Are there installation codes or code requirements that say this cannot be done or that specify how far the tile must be from the window?

:)

[image]

Comment: It's not apparent why there's so little window showing in that rough opening. Is it installed over the RO, rather than into it?

Comment: Not sure what RO means.  I do not know why there is so little showing, my handyman is currently placing it in.  Currently there is no tile in, but when the tile goes in there will be very little window frame showing.  I am replacing the tile around my bathtub, and the window is in the tub area.

Comment: Underneath on the sides was concrete blocks from the outside.  But there use to be a one inch margin on the each side of the window.

Comment: "rough opening ... RO ..." You said all that in your question. I'd like to know more about the window install to properly answer.

Comment: As long as the tile is not above the frame it should be fine.